# Add numbering to the view that contain condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem where I want to add index numbering 1.2.3.4..etc at my table but the table content have @if($t1,t2,t3,..etc > 0) condition on it, if I hard code the number in view, if it meets `$t1,t2,t3,..etc < 0`, it will skip the index number

```
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>No.</th>
       <th>Subject name</th>
       <th>No. of students</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        @if($t1>0)
         <tr class="gradeX">
          <td>1</td>
          <td><a href="{{url('/admin/technology-and-informationsystem')}}" target="_blank">Technology & Information System</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t1 }}</td>
         </tr>
        @endif
        @if($t2>0)
         <tr class="gradeX">
          <td>2</td>
          <td><a href="{{url('/admin/discrete-structure')}}" target="_blank">Discrete Structure</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t2 }}</td>
         </tr>
        @endif
```

The output should show the numbering without skipping any number even it skip the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the `@if`-conditions to only surround the table data that you don't want to be visible unless the condition is met. If I understand your question correctly, you want to show every row with their number and only show the rest of the row if the condition is met. If this is what you want, you could do:

```
     <tr class="gradeX">
      <td>1</td>
      @if($t1>0)
      <td><a href="{{url('/admin/technology-and-informationsystem')}}" target="_blank">Technology & Information System</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t1 }}</td>
      @endif
     </tr>
     <tr class="gradeX">
      <td>2</td>
      @if($t2>0)
      <td><a href="{{url('/admin/discrete-structure')}}" target="_blank">Discrete Structure</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">{{ $t2 }}</td>
      @endif
     </tr>
```